# How do the View and the Model interact with the sub ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediator

I have an MVVM based WPF application with the sub ViewModels interacting with each other and the main ViewModel via a mediator class (mediator design pattern). Does the main ViewModel somehow expose the properties of the sub ViewModels to the View and the Model? One way would be to make the main ViewModel still implement the interfaces of sub ViewModels and replace the functionality of the interface functions with calls to the mediator but then these callbacks have no return type and the View and Model may require some data from subViewModels. For example,

`MainWindow` wants `subViewModel1.state` but knows only the `mainViewModel`. In my current implementation the `mainViewModel` can only set the `subViewModel1.state` and `subViewModel1` can send it to the `mainViewModel` but this would an async callback.

Comment: you can make use of service locator concept to achieve the same.